# Making a mobile multiplayer game using Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, mobile

Okay I have been working on a personal project for about 6 months. I went from a novice coder with only learning from Matlab and a few other random projects in Java to trying to make a game from scratch.

I have some educational background in programming (I have done some CS assignments) and I tend to understand things when I get thrown into them.

The current issue that I am having with the game I am making using Unity is that I am unsure what I need to do in terms of making it available as a multiplayer game.

Basically the game is like Clash Royale by Supercell but my own version. Clash Royale for those that do not know, is a Player vs. Player game where 2 people are connected that have similar "ratings". They basically use trophies to determine how many wins and losses a player has received and tries to match players by their trophies.

Currently I am working through this one step at a time. My first step is to get 2 people to connect to a game and see that both players are on. After this I would like to add a character and the opposing character should essentially have their screen flipped 180 degrees (this is seen in Clash Royale). My current issue lies within choosing and understanding how I can make multiplayer work.

I know that Unity supports client-Server with client as host, and Client-Server with dedicated server. My issue with using Unity's built in Matchmaking is that only 20 CCU (Concurrent users) can be playing for the free version. The price then begins to increase from there and I am unsure how popular the game I am making will be since it is my first game. I would like to get by doing this for free and find a long term solution so I do not have recode later.

I think a dedicated server may be overkill for a project like this so I have decided that this method may not be worth the hassle for this game.

I do believe it is possible to have 2 users connect in a unity game without CCU being used up. However doing so over diffferent networks is not understood yet on my part. I think the only way to do this is through port forwarding but I am unsure if that is still true with a mobile game. I am also unsure if this is unethical. My thoughts on the matter are that people can play phone games in almost any location without any suspicion. For example playing a game using an airports Wi-fi is not a big deal. But do those phone games that allow players to connect with one another use port forwarding or some other way of connecting to each other?

If port forwarding is standard and not a big deal then I think I will continue to learn how to code port forwarding so that way players can auto join each other. If there is a different/better/more ethical way then I would rather look into how to do that.

Please let me know if I need to clarify this question.
Thank you.

**EDIT**
After receiving some comments, it sounds as though I need a public server so that users can then access this server. My next question is then what is the cheapest way to do. I believe that I can use a spare computer to run a server but is this the best way to have a "free" server? (still technically need to pay for maintenance/operating on that spare computer).

My understanding is there are a few ways to host a server that all vary. The ways that I am currently thinking, if they are possible, are Unity's built in networking, Amazon Web Services, a personal website as a server, or a computer that I leave on at home that hosts the server.

Comment: "_I think I will continue to learn how to code port forwarding_" You don't do that. That is configured in the router or firewall of the network to which a host connects. For mobile devices, and for users on different private networks, you will need to have a public server. Don't make the mistake of trying to write network applications before you actually understand networking. That is how we end up with security holes in our networks.

Comment: I suspect you should be able to make it work relatively easily over a LAN network. That way you should be able to set it up without port forward/hosting, albeit it would only work on LAN. As of now I don't know enough about the pricing and such for CCU to guide on that. I would assume that phone games normally have a master server which connects all the players, which I believe does so the individual player does not need to port forward. Disclaimer: I am not super experienced with multiplayer, just sharing my understandings thus far.

Comment: @Ron Maupin, I did say that If it was a good idea. I do thank you for your insight though. It sounds like there is no way around having a public server. And I am trying to understand networking as I go. I do a lot of research before I set up anything.

Comment: @Doh09, My problem is that I want to go over different private networks. I think Ron explained this well and that I should explore making a public server.

Comment: Well the public server is what I called a master server. But yes, that seems like what you need.

Comment: I downvoted because this question does not seem to be really about programming at all, but how to setup your networking infrastructure for an online game